# Should we edit out company names when it is not relevant to the question?

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions

Regarding [How can I tell whether my dog was euthanized in a painful fashion?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/how-can-i-tell-whether-my-dog-was-euthanized-in-a-painful-fashion) , the asker stated they went to PetSmart (a pet supply and in-house veterinarian chain) to handle their dog's euthanasia.  The verbiage used read as though he had to justify using PetSmart rather than a standalone veterinarian, and could infer that the service received may have been less competent than at, say, a standalone.

I am not defending the company practices, but I generalized the references in an edit, rather than leave them in.  If the asker has a problem with the company, that is their problem; implications of slight that aren't relevant to the question should be removed.

Was this the correct course of action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I definitely think so. If there was a question about in-store veterinarian compared to standalone practices, it may be warranted to include it as a generic term. I think the same thing is appropriate whether you received treatment from a county clinic vs your regular vet. The specific county isn't necessary to make the distinction.

In this case, however, I think the edit you made is perfect. That question could apply to that user or myself, who uses the family-owned office down the street.

Comment: I agree, it's probably wise to avoid the risk of becoming an unintended review site for businesses.

Comment: Check out the comment from the user on my answer. Still gets his dig in.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with that edit in this case; the detail wasn't important to the question.

But we shouldn't generalize from this to "detail is bad", either.  *Appropriate* detail is important to avoid vague questions that are hard to answer well.  The trick is knowing what's appropriate.  When in doubt, I think more specificity is better than less; it can be edited out if unneeded, but can't as easily be edited in if missing.

On technology sites questions generally specify not only products but versions.  When I asked a newbie question on Travel about resolving an airline problem I was asked to specify the airline (though I'd thought the question more general).  *Details help*, so long as they aren't overdone or spammy.

That said, the details usually shouldn't be front and center, like in the question title or the opening sentence.  Footnotes or a "specifics" section at the end of a post would be a good compromise.

Comment: It's that one sentence of justification explaining WHY he went there, "I took the dog to Pet smart because that is where it had received most of it's care", which followed a prior declaration naming the company, that really stuck out to me.  It's like he was calling them out on a "bad practice" when this exact same situation could have taken place at any vet.  Full disclosure: I shop at Pet Supermarket.

Comment: I just looked at your edit and I agree -- that was the right call in this case.  I just don't want people to generalize to "detail is bad".  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hence the "not relevant to the question" in the title of this question. :-)

Comment: The 'bad' questions that name specific entities tend to come in the form of 'Such and such is horrible, am I right?' and can _usually_ be closed down pretty quickly for unrelated concerns. As long as you're making a good faith effort to (1) ask an answerable question and (2) trying to maintain a constructive and impartial tone, then details should be whatever you think might be relevant for those that wish to provide answers (or, what Monica said).